# scopeButtonTitles is always nil

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I don't understand why is my scopeButtonTitles always nil. I followed the tutorial from [RayWenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/76519/add-table-view-search-swift) but the difference is that my array of elements my search bar is supposed to get the scope button titles from is loaded from a database.

But I carefully checked and my array is well loaded and not nil. When is the scopeButtonTitles set? Maybe it is before my array is initialised?

Here is my code:

```
var bottlesArray: Array<Bottle>!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadBottles() // loads elements from a DB and initialise bottlesArray
}

func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
    // Filter the array using the filter method
    self.filteredBottles = self.bottlesArray.filter({(bottle: Bottle) -> Bool in
        var categoryMatch = (scope == "All") || (bottle.category == scope)

        // The two following line put the search string AND the matching string in Lower case and accent tolerent so, for example "Dôle" == "dole" -> true
        var lowerCaseNoAccentTitle: String = NSString(data: bottle.title.lowercaseString.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        var lowerCaseNoAccentSearchText: String = NSString(data: searchText.lowercaseString.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

        var stringMatch = lowerCaseNoAccentTitle.rangeOfString(lowerCaseNoAccentSearchText)
        return categoryMatch && (stringMatch != nil)
    })
}

func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController!, shouldReloadTableForSearchString searchString: String!) -> Bool {
    let scopes = self.searchDisplayController!.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles as [String]
    let selectedScope = scopes[self.searchDisplayController!.searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex] as String
    self.filterContentForSearchText(searchString, scope: selectedScope)
    return true
}

func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController!,
    shouldReloadTableForSearchScope searchOption: Int) -> Bool {
        let scope = self.searchDisplayController!.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles as [String]
        self.filterContentForSearchText(self.searchDisplayController!.searchBar.text, scope: scope[searchOption])
        return true
}
```

So, to be clear, `self.searchDisplayController!.searchBar` is not nil but `scopeButtonTitles` is. If I set manually `self.searchDisplayController!.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles` then the scope bar works. But in the tutorial it is automatically loaded.

I do not really understand when the `scopeButtonTitles` array is supposed to be populated.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of question you should ask the original author of the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

In the demo project, should have a initialisation for `scopeButtonTitles` which I think you are missing, you should add the following line in `viewDidLoad` function of you project.

```
searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["All"]
```